# Can't find create .pro file option in QT VS Tool

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I create a QTWidget project use VS2022. I  want to use QT creator to open it. But I can't find the create `.pro` file option in QT VS Tool and there is no cmakelists file, just a `.sln` file.

Should I convert the `.sln` to the `.pro` or cmakelists file?

The QT VS TOOLs' menu is just like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub Thank your help. I  don't find the `create  Basic .pro File`in the QT VS TOOL.

Comment: [Qt VS Tools for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2022) says it's possible to "*Import and export of Qt project files (.pro) and project include files (.pri).*", but the export option does not seem to be there in your menu, so I visited [Qt bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG) link at the bottom and found this: [QTVSADDINBUG-1128: Export Project to .pri file not available anymore in Qt-menu](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTVSADDINBUG/issues/QTVSADDINBUG-1128?filter=allopenissues).

Comment: @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub I see it.Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: I have a same problem, I can't find create  Basic .pro File in my VS2022. can anyone help me?

Comment: Thank you for your help sincerely  @AbderrahmeneRayeneMihoub . The function is removed in QTVSTOOLs v3.0.1 in [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTVSADDINBUG/issues/QTVSADDINBUG-1128?filter=allissues) .I can solve this problem use v2.10.1.

Comment: @zeekzhen you can use QTVSTOOLs v2.10.1.